# Android: Not able to select image from gallery

Tags: android, cursor, gallery

I am trying to pick a picture from the gallery and set it as a background for the view. Now, I am able to select pics as long as they are on my SD card. But as my gallery is in sync with my picasa album and when I try to select one of those pics, the cursor is returning NULL. Below is my code.

```
            Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = managedQuery(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
```

The selected image has URI of "
https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-thIdOA38IO0/SY8GG8PqW4I/AAAAAAAABKA/f3XpPvY9JHo/s1024/Picture%252520007.jpg"

Can someone help?

Thx!
Rahul.

Answer (score 0):

```
Uri selectedImage = Uri.parse(imageReturnedIntent.getDataString());
```

Try the above line which return the Uri of selectedImage.

Comment: this isn't working. But I guess, every image downloaded from internet, they are cached in the /sdcard/Android/data folder. But I am not sure how to map the above URI to the actual cached file. Any help is appreciated.